# Advantages/disadvantages of different representations of non-anticipativity constraints

Tags: stochastic-programming

When reading various papers about two-stage (or multi-stage) stochastic programs with recourse, a common representation of the non-anticipativity constraints is:
$$
\sum_{i}H_ix_i=h,
$$
where $i$ indexes the scenarios, and the matrices $H_i$ and vector $h$ are typically not specified (see, e.g., [this paper by Carøe and Schultz](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/files/256/SC-96-46.pdf)).

**Question:** What are some common choices of $H_i$ and $h$ used to enforce non-anticipativity? What advantages and disadvantages do these choices have when used algorithmically (in decomposition approaches, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
If one define $H_i$ as an operator, not necessarily a matrix, I can think of what happens in progressive hedging and go for something like: $H_i(x_i)=I(x_i−x^*)+1/2(x_i−x^*)^TI(x_i−x^*)$.
If in the matrix format: $H_i=1/rIx_i$ and $h=x^*$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are three scenarios $i$ in the second stage and two time steps $t$. With
$$
x_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    x_{11} \\
    x_{12} \\
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
x_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    x_{21} \\
    x_{22} \\
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
x_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
    x_{31} \\
    x_{32} \\
    \end{pmatrix},
$$
one obvious choice would be
$$
H_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
H_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
H_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Another possibility:

$$
H_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
H_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix},\quad
H_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Both with $h = 0$.

Visually, the block structure is more obvious in the latter formulation. I don't see any major advantages or disadvantages by using one or the other.